# How to know if a file is being copied?

Tags: c, file

I am currently trying to check wether the copy of a file  from a directory to another is done.
I would like to know if the target file is still being copied.

So I would like to get the number of file descriptors openned on this file.
I use C langage and don't really find a way to resolve that problem.

Comment: Impossible to get the size of the source file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of it, I would recommend using the copy-move idiom on the program *doing* the copying:

```
cp file1 otherdir/.file1.tmp
mv otherdir/.file1.tmp otherdir/file1
```

The `mv` just changes some filesystem entries and is atomic and very fast compared to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, try the `lsof` command, which lists all of the open files on your system.

edit 1: The only C language feature that comes to mind is the [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) function. You might be able to use that with the struct's `st_mtime` (last modification time) field - once that value stops changing (for, say, a period of 10 seconds), then you could assume that file copy operation has stopped.

edit 2: also, on linux, you could traverse [/proc/[pid]/fd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) to see which files are open. The files in there are symlinks, but C's `readlink()` function could tell you its path, so you could see whether it is still open. Using `getpid()`, you would know the process ID of your program (if you are doing a file copy from within your program) to know where to look in /proc.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of LSOF in the C langage ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to open the file for writing, there's a good chance that the OS has finished the copy and has released its lock on it. Different operating systems may behave differently for this, however.

Another approach is to open both the source and destination files for reading and compare their sizes. If they're of identical size, the copy has very likely finished. You can use `fseek()` and `ftell()` to determine the size of a file in C:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fp);
```

Comment: This is basically only true on Windows. Any POSIX conformant OS does not behave as you describe.

Comment: Hence my comment that different OSes may behave differently :) Anyway, which part of the answer are you referring to: the OS allowing updates prior to the completion of the copy, or the fseek/ftell approach to determining the size of the copied file?

Answer (score 0):

(This answer makes the big, big assumption that this will be running on Linux.)

The C source code of `lsof`, a tool that tells which programs currently have an open file descriptor to a specific file, is [freely available](ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/). However, just to warn you, I couldn't make any sense out of it. There are references to reading kernel memory, so to me it's either voodoo or black magic.

That said, nothing prevents you from running `lsof` through your own program. Running third-party programs from your own program is normally something you try to avoid for several reasons, like security (if a rogue user changes `lsof` for a malicious program, it will run with your program's privileges, with potentially **catastrophic** consequences) but inspecting the `lsof` source code, I came to the conclusion that there's no public API to determine which program has which file open. If you're not afraid of people changing programs in `/usr/sbin`, you might consider this.

```
int isOpen(const char* file)
{
    char* command;
    // BE AWARE THAT THIS WILL NOT WORK IF THE FILE NAME CONTAINS A DOUBLE QUOTE
    // OR IF IT CAN SOMEHOW BE ALTERED THROUGH SHELL EXPANSION
    // you should either try to fix it yourself, or use a function of the `exec`
    // family that won't trigger shell expansion.
    // It would be an EXTREMELY BAD idea to call `lsof` without an absolute path
    // since it could result in another program being run. If this is not where
    // `lsof` resides on your system, change it to the appropriate absolute path.
    asprintf(&command, "/usr/sbin/lsof \"%s\"", file);
    int result = system(command);

    free(command);
    return result;
}
```

If you also need to know which program has your file open (presumably `cp`?), you can use `popen` to read the output of `lsof` in a similar fashion. `popen` descriptors behave like `fopen` descriptors, so all you need to do is `fread` them and see if you can find your program's name. On my machine, `lsof` output looks like this:

```
$ lsof document.pdf 
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
SomeApp 873 felix  txt    REG   14,3   303260 5165763 document.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic mistake is trying to synchronize a C program with a shell tool/external program that's not intended for synchronization. If you have some degree of control over the program/script doing the copying, you should modify it to perform advisory locking of some sort (preferably `fcntl`-based) on the target file. Then your other program can simply block on acquiring the lock.

If you don't have any control over the program performing the copy, the only solutions depend on non-portable hacks like `lsof` or Linux `inotify` API.

Answer (score 0):

As poundifdef mentioned, the fstat() function can give you the current modification time. But fstat also gives you the size of the file.

Back in the dim dark ages of C when I was monitoring files being copied by various programs I had no control over I always:

1. Waited until the target file size was >= the source size, and

   Waited until the target modification time was at least N  seconds older than the current time. N being a number such a 5, and set larger if experience showed that was necessary. Yes 5 seconds seems extreme, but it is safe.

If you don't know what the target file is then the only real choice you have is #2, but user a larger N to allow for the worse case network and local CPU delays, with a healthy safety factor.

Answer (score 0):

using boost libs will solve the issue

```
boost::filesystem::fstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

if(fileStream.is_open())
    //not getting copied
else
    //Wait, the file is getting copied
```